# How to merge documents from different collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I know this question has been asked a couple times but I couldn't get mine to work.

Here's my steps

```
db.col1.insert({"product_id" : 1, "title" : "Sharpie"});
db.col1.insert({"product_id" : 2, "title" : "Sticky"});
db.col2.insert({"product_id" : 1, "price" : 99});
db.col2.insert({"product_id" : 2, "price" : 30});

col1_map = function() {
    emit(this.product_id, {"title" : this.title});
}

col1_r = function(key, values) {
    var result = {
        "title" : ""
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.title = value.title;
    });

    return result;
}

col2_map = function() {
    emit(this.product_id, {"price" : this.price});
};

col2_r = function(key, values) {
    var result = {
        "price" : ""
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.price = value.price;
    });

    return result;
};

res = db.col1.mapReduce(col1_map, col1_r, {out: {merge : 'joined'}});
res = db.col2.mapReduce(col2_map, col2_r, {out: {merge : 'joined'}});
```

The results I got is this

```
>> db.joined.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "price" : 99 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "price" : 30 } }
```

What I want it this

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "price" : 99, "title" : "Sharpie" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "price" : 30, "title" : "Sticky" } }
```

Not sure if I miss something obvious.

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a one-time processing job (i.e. tyring to reconfigure your schemas for future use) or as a common operation (i.e. you want something like this to happen each time you query the db)?

Comment: It's a one time process. I just want to merge my data to see the joined data. I realise that it could have been done in a different way but I have all the data in Mongo already.

Comment: Ah, then I'd recommend not trying to do it with `mapReduce` and just doing it in a brute-force way with `for` loops, etc. Just iterate through your ids, pulling out the information you need, and then insert that into a new collection, which could all be done with scripting in the mongo console. If you want to stick with mapReduce, I'm sure there's someone else here with more experience in that than me :)

Comment: Thanks @3rf but I have over 10 million documents that's why I'm looking into mapReduce. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want by changing your col2_r reduce function as follows:

```
col2_r = function(key, values) {

    var result = {};

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        if ('title' in value)
            result.title = value.title;
        if ('price' in value)
            result.price = value.price;
    });

    return result;
};
```

And then change the output action to "reduce":

```
res = db.col1.mapReduce(col1_map, col1_r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
res = db.col2.mapReduce(col2_map, col2_r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
```

This will cause documents with identical keys in the output to be passed through the reduce function, which does the merging of fields.

By the way, the col1_r reduce function works as written, but it can be simplified as follows:

```
col1_r = function(key, values) {
    return values[0]
}
```

Hope this helps!